# How to call a function using object prototype in Javascript

Tags: javascript, prototype

I had a doubt.Is this possible to call one function/method present inside one class using object prototype in Javascript ? If possible then can anybody make the below code correct.

```
(function(){
    window.Peer=function(){
        var peer=this;
        peer.getMessage=function(){
            alert("hello!!! This is very good site.")
        }
    }
})();


<button type="button" id="btn">Click here</button>
<script>
document.getElementById('btn').onclick=function(){
    Peer.prototype.getMessage();
}
```

The above code throwing error.Please give me some idea to resolve this.

Comment: you can test with Inspect Element within Console

Comment: you can run it as it using `Peer(getMessage())` or `Peer.call(getMessage())`

Comment: FYI you are getting an error because you haven't added the function to Peer.prototype

Comment: @Jaromanda X : Can you make this correct.?

Answer (score 1):

```
(function(){
    window.Peer=function(){}
    window.Peer.prototype.getMessage=function(){
        alert("hello!!! This is very good site.")
    }
})();
<button type="button" id="btn">Click here</button>
document.getElementById('btn').onclick=function(){
    var peer = new Peer();
    peer.getMessage();
}
```

you can treat Peer as an object

Comment: I know this but i want to use prototype.

Answer (score 0):

Every first thing I would suggest you to read more about [JavaScript Object](http://javascriptissexy.com/oop-in-javascript-what-you-need-to-know/)

`getMessage` is a function attached with `peer` variable which has local scope. You can't access it from outside world unless you create a object of `Peer`.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>

(function(){
    window.Peer=function(){
        var peer=this;
        peer.getMessage=function(){
            alert("hello!!! This is very good site.")
        };
    }
})();

window.onload=function(){
    document.getElementById('btn').onclick=function(){
        var peer = new Peer();
        peer.getMessage();
    };
}
    </script>
    </head>

<body>
    <button type="button" id="btn">Click here</button>    
</body>
</html>
```